# Sed: adding to end of a specific line

Tags: linux, unix, sed, latex, ascii

Trying to write a Sed script to convert man pages to latex. 
Need to add a space and \\ at the end of every line whose first non-blank character is either a "+" or a "-". What I did:

```
    /[. \t]-[a-zA-Z]/s/$/ \\\\/
    /[. \t]+[a-zA-Z]/s/$/ \\\\/
```

I figured that the man pages had spaces or a tab of blankspace before a "-" or "+" was encountered so I added the space and tab to the address. My problem is that it adds the \\ to the end of every line that has a "-" or "+" with a character. Example output:

```
            -daystart \\
                    Measure times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, ctime, \\
                    -mmin, and -mtime) from the beginning of today \\
                    rather than from 24 hours ago.
```

It must be in a single Sed script that could convert multiple man pages to latex so line numbers as addresses wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
/^[. \t][. \t]*[-+][a-zA-Z]/s/$/ \\\\/
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the `-` or the `+` at the beginning of the line (after some whitespace), then you can do:

```
sed '/^[. \t]-[a-zA-Z]/s/$/ \\\\/' inputfile
```

Note the `^`, which matches the beginning of a line.

Moreover, I think you can remove this part `[a-zA-Z]`, or why do you need it? Then you can also search for `-` and `+` at the same time by using `[-+]`:

```
sed '/^[. \t][-+]/s/$/ \\\\
```

But maybe I misunderstood what exactly you want to do.